# How do I get the org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request from within my servlet

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

Consider this bit of code.  It's a work in progress but the goal is
to get my hands on an NIO channel that I can use to create a full-duplex
RubyIO instance (org.jruby.RubyIO), that is selectable by an NIO Selector.

But first I want an NIO Channel ...

```
        //  This call returns a `javax.servlet.ServletRequest` but the underlying
        // instance was created by Jetty - it seems to me - and is actually an
        // `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request`
        ServletRequest srv_req = this.http_servlet_request_wrapper.getRequest();
        Request req;
        ClassLoader cl1 = Request.class.getClassLoader();
        ClassLoader cl2 = srv_req.getClass().getClassLoader();

        System.out.println("DBG: cl1: " + cl1.toString());
        // => DBG: cl1: WebAppClassLoader{66233253}@3f2a3a5

        System.out.println("DBG: cl2: " + cl2.toString());
        // => DBG: cl2: java.net.URLClassLoader@63947c6b

        if (srv_req instanceof Request) {
            System.out.println("DBG: srv_req IS REQUEST");
            req = (Request)srv_req;
            System.out.println("DBG: req class: " + req.getClass().getName());
        } else {
            System.out.println("DBG: srv_req IS NOT REQUEST");
            System.out.println("DBG: srv_req class: " + srv_req.getClass().getName());
            throw new Exception("<expletive deleted>!");
        }

        HttpChannel http_channel = req.getHttpChannel();
        EndPoint end_point = http_channel.getEndPoint();
```

What gets output on the console ...

```
DBG: cl1: WebAppClassLoader{66233253}@3f2a3a5
DBG: cl2: java.net.URLClassLoader@63947c6b
DBG: srv_req IS NOT REQUEST
DBG: srv_req class: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request
```

Finally the exception gets thrown.

So it seems that `instanceof` is saying that `srv_req` is not an instance of
`Reuest` because the classloaders are not the same.  The class of `srv_req`
is `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request`, though.  But in the servlet I cannot
treat it as such and I cannot cast it.

I've read https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-classloading.html
but it's still not clear to me how to get access to `srv_req` as a
`org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request` instance.

I suspect that I am not supposed to be able to do this from the servlet, but it
can't hurt to ask.

Can I access the `javax.servlet.ServletRequest`, returned from my
`HttpServletRequestWrapper` object, as what it appears to be, an
`org.eclispe.jetty.server.Request` instance?

Alternatively, can I create a full duplex NIO channel from what I CAN get access
to in the servlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to get the `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request` from `javax.servlet.HttpServletRequest` just use ...

```java
Request baseRequest = Request.getBaseRequest(httpServletRequest);
```

But that's not going to get you very far.

[`org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.27.v20200227/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/HttpChannel.java) and [`org.eclipse.jetty.io.EndPoint`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.27.v20200227/jetty-io/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/io/EndPoint.java) are not exposing NIO interfaces or behaviors to applications.

They are internal classes that implement the HTTP spec behavior via a single interface, to handle things like ...

- Transfer Encodings
- Chunking
- Content Encodings
- Gzip
- Multipart Encoding
- etc ..

And that's just what HTTP/1.1 brings to the table, if you start to use HTTP/2 things get even more complicated (with a physical connection controlling many virtual streams).

But what if you don't want to use, or care about, HTTP?

You could upgrade the connection and get out from underneath HTTP by using your own `Connection` object.

```java
jettyEndPoint.setConnection(myConnection);
jettyEndPoint.upgrade(myConnection);
```

Don't forget to implement `Connection.UpgradeTo` to get the lingering (unprocessed) bytes from the prior connection.

But that still doesn't get you NIO, as the `EndPoint` isn't relinquished from Jetty, and it's doing the selector management and low level protocol behaviors still. (a Stream from HTTP/2 for example)

Ok, so back to HTTP, what options do you have left?

Nothing that exposes or lets you manage the NIO selector.

You would have to fake the selector for jruby.

If you want to stick to HTTP, then use the servlet spec Async I/O behaviors as your Jetty side API layer.

If you don't want to stick to HTTP, then upgrade the connection away from HTTP,  just be sure you say so in the HTTP conversation first using the appropriate headers (eg: `Connection: upgrade`).

Comment: Joakim,  Thanks for your answer.  I have tried `Request.getBaseRequest(httpServletRequest);` but it's returning `null`.  I may attempt to upgrade the connection.  Can you elaborate on the most straightforward way to achieve that, please?   I did find an issue where you point out why Jetty does not implement the `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper#upgrade` call.  I found that after I attempted to use it.  Can you point out a recommended way?

Comment: If your use of `Request.getBaseRequest(httpServletRequest)` returns null you have some serious issues to work out first, there's something fundamentally wrong on your environment, that method should never return null for legitimate requests handled by Jetty. (even complicated wrapped requests would not return null).   And you'll need it to work for the upgrade path.  For an example on how to upgrade, see https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.27.v20200227/jetty-websocket/websocket-client/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/client/WebSocketUpgradeRequest.java#L589-L654